URL changes but components not rendered in Angular
I am new to angular I am mobile developer ,
I am using angular 17 but I have issue the only home page renders on the screen I can't navigate to any other component the url changes but the same page appears
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './employee/employees/employees-component/employees-component';
import { EmployeesService } from './employee/common/employees-service';
import { provideAnimationsAsync } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations/async';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { LoadingComponent } from './core/compnents/loading-component';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { AddEmployeeComponent } from './employee/add-employee.ts/add-employee-component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [EmployeesComponent, LoadingComponent, AddEmployeeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [EmployeesService, provideAnimationsAsync('animations')],
  bootstrap: [EmployeesComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}    

app router
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddEmployeeComponent } from './employee/add-employee.ts/add-employee-component';
import { EmployeesComponent } from './employee/employees/employees-component/employees-component';
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: EmployeesComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'add',
    component: AddEmployeeComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}

I added router-outlet at the bottom of the file
but still networking
when I created my project I enabled option to use app modules
<div class="table-container">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="employees" class="employee-table">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.id }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.name }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Age. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.age }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="phoneNumber">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Phone Number. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.phoneNumber }} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="edit(element)">Edit</button>
        <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="delete(element)">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <loading [loading]="loading" class="loading-spinner"></loading>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>


and the above code is my app-employees-component the home component

Any errors in the browser console?

no I enabled the logs for navigation no error appears

Please paste your template code here(app.component.html)

Where's is your home page? I didn't see HomeComponent.





this is my home page called AddEmployeeComponent
Where's the code to trigger the navigation?

this.router.navigate(['/add']);
but when I try to open the url manually
http://localhost:4200/add
like so it not doing anything

Why did you bootstrap EmployeesComponent instead of AppComponent? in AppModule?

You should post a workable example, and mark the file name before each code block.

please add a working example or stackblitz url so we can check how the code flows and what is the project str

as per your code you add component should be rendered below the table so when you navigate please check below the table
